# How to get jquery to show the count each li and output the number

Tags: jquery, html

I need jquery to loop through each div but only count the number of li's inside it's respective div, and then output the number li's for each.

The problem is it loops through them all but gathers all the information in p tag, and displays it. instead of only the colors for each of them.

Here is a codepen, to showcase it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRqGjZ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapper>ul>li").each(function() {
    var numItems = $('.color').length;
    $("#numberofitems").html(numItems);
    $("#numberofitems").append(" Colors");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
  </ul>
  <p id="numberofitems"></p>
  <!-- Output 4 COLORS here -->
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
    <li class="color">Color 5</li>
  </ul>
  <p id="numberofitems"></p>
  <!-- Output 5 COLORS here -->
</div>
```

Comment: first: id should be unique use class instead `<p class="numberofitems"></p> ` and loop through `.numberofitems` and use `.prev('ul').find('li.color').length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note `id`s should be unique. That is why I changed,

```
<p id="numberofitems"></p>
```

to

```
<p class="numberofitems"></p>
```

See explanation comments in code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapper").each(function() { // loop trough the wrappers
    // $(this) is the wrapper
    var numItems = $(this).find('.color').length; // count the colors inside this wrapper
    $(this).find('.numberofitems').html('Output ' + numItems + ' COLORS here'); // add the number inside this wrapper to numberofitems
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="numberofitems"></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
    <li class="color">Color 5</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="numberofitems"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through the list items when you need to loop through the divs. You also can't re-use IDs so use classes instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrapper").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".numberofitems").html($(this).find('.color').length + " Colors");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="numberofitems"></p>
  <!-- Output 4 COLORS here -->
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">Color 1</li>
    <li class="color">Color 2</li>
    <li class="color">Color 3</li>
    <li class="color">Color 4</li>
    <li class="color">Color 5</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="numberofitems"></p>
  <!-- Output 5 COLORS here -->
</div>
```